# Azure B2C ADFS autologin logout failed

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, saml, saml-2.0, azure-ad-b2c

There's an issue I'm facing with B2C policies and AD login.

I have two signin policies, both are connected with separate AD.
Signin policies work with SAML2 protocol, connect with AD through OIDC.

AD technical profile looks like:

```
        <ClaimsProvider>
        <Domain>microsoftonline.com</Domain>
        <DisplayName>Login using ADFS</DisplayName>
        <TechnicalProfiles>
            <TechnicalProfile Id="Microsoft-OpenID">
                <DisplayName>Microsoft ADFS</DisplayName>
                <Description>Login with your ADFS account</Description>
                <Protocol Name="OpenIdConnect" />
                <OutputTokenFormat>JWT</OutputTokenFormat>
                <Metadata>
                    <Item Key="METADATA">https://login.microsoftonline.com/adfstenant.onmicrosoft.com/.well-known/openid-configuration</Item>
                    <Item Key="client_id">000000-00000-0000-0000-0000000000</Item>
                    <Item Key="ValidTokenIssuerPrefixes">https://sts.windows.net/000000-000-000-0000-000000</Item>
                    <Item Key="scope">openid</Item>
                    <Item Key="response_mode">form_post</Item>
                    <Item Key="response_types">id_token</Item>
                    <Item Key="DiscoverMetadataByTokenIssuer">true</Item>
                    <Item Key="UsePolicyInRedirectUri">false</Item>
                </Metadata>
                <CryptographicKeys>
                    <Key Id="client_secret" StorageReferenceId="B2C_1A_ADFSSecret" />
                </CryptographicKeys>
                <OutputClaims>
                    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="socialIdpUserId" PartnerClaimType="oid" />
                    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="displayName" PartnerClaimType="name" />
                    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" PartnerClaimType="unique_name" />
                    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="identityProvider" DefaultValue="ADFS" />
                    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="authenticationSource" PartnerClaimType="iss" />
                    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="sub" PartnerClaimType="oid" />
                </OutputClaims>
                <OutputClaimsTransformations>
                    <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CreateRandomUPNUserName"/>
                    <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CreateUserPrincipalName"/>
                    <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CreateAlternativeSecurityId"/>
                </OutputClaimsTransformations>
                <UseTechnicalProfileForSessionManagement ReferenceId="SM-SocialLogin" />
            </TechnicalProfile>
        </TechnicalProfiles>
    </ClaimsProvider>
```

I have the next behavior:

1. Log into ADFS using B2C custom policy 1;
2. After that login using B2C custom policy 2, login is proceeded automatically, because I have already logged into AD;
3. Perform global logout from policy 1 or 2.

As a result, logout request to AD has status cancelled, B2C policy returns SAMLRequest instead of SAMLResponse to my SingleLogout endpoint.

Single logout returns SAMLResponse to the policy and the exception is happened on policy side.

It looks like logout from B2C was completed, if I try to send login request login page is shown.

Moreover, if I signin again using ADFS signin button on that page, I will be able to logout successfully.

There's two question I have:

1. Why AD logout request "https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenant/oauth2/logout" has cancelled status
2. Why B2C policy returns SAML LogoutRequest to my application instead of SAML Logout response in that case.

Comment: Can you share if you are using SAML to call into Azure AD B2C? (I understand your IDP is OpenID Connect).

Comment: @omer-iqbal yes I use SAML to call Azure B2C. Do you want me to share B2C policy or SAML request?